# Rackable 2U LCD Personalization

Tags: rack, rackmount

So I have several of these machines, however rather than physically labeling them (which I'd rather not do because there is really no place to do it, I would like to have the computer name displayed on the LCD screen on the front of it, is there a way to do this in the BIOS?

**EDIT:**
Motherboard: Rackable
Product Name: .........................
Serial Number: 1428266
BIOS: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
Version: V1.22.Vista.R4I
Release Date: 06/26/2008

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is referring to the [LCD front panel](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/w/wiki/3869.lcd-info-screen-and-led-alert-panel-on-poweredge-12th-generation-servers.aspx) on Dell servers. These can be set with customized text (e.g. a hostname) using the OMSA tools. For instance, in Linux:

```
omconfig chassis frontpanel lcdindex=1 config=custom text=hostname
```

Comment: this is actually a Rackable Systems machine. It doesn't really have any model information, but they are Dual Core, 16GB Ram, and this was the info running the BIOS Command from dmidecode: 
Motherboard: Rackable
Product Name: .........................
Serial Number: 1428266

BIOS: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
Version: V1.22.Vista.R4I
Release Date: 06/26/2008